# Counting the number of occurrences of an ID in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, count

I have a dataframe with roughly 6000 objects that looks like this:
[image]

V1 and V2 are IDs of people who have communicated with each other (messages from V1 to V2), and V3 can be ignored. I am trying to find out the number of persons someone has communicated with i.e. the number of times an ID appears in either column V1 or V2 (I removed the duplicates). Can I use the `count` function to do this? If so, how?

Comment: Try `table(unlist(df1[1:2]))`  The idea is to `unlist` the first two columns into a `vector` and apply `table` to get the frequency/count of individual ids.  If we need to keep both columns, just do `table(df[1:2])` or may be `table(do.call(paste, df[1:2]))`

Answer (score 1):

With `table`:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(V1 = sample(x = 50, replace = T),
                 V2 = sample(x = 50, replace = T))

df$V1 <- as.factor(df$V1)
df$V2 <- as.factor(df$V2)
table(df$V1)
```

```
> table(df$V1)

 1  2  4  6  7  9 10 11 14 18 19 20 21 24 25 27 28 29 30 32 33 34 35 36 37 39 40 42 44 45 46 47 48 50 
 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  3  2  1  1  4  1  1  3  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  1  2  2  3  2  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

```
table(df$V2)
```

```
> table(df$V2)

 3  4  5  7  8 11 12 13 15 16 17 18 20 21 22 23 24 26 31 33 34 36 38 39 40 41 42 44 45 46 49 
 1  1  2  1  1  1  1  3  1  1  4  1  2  2  2  2  3  1  1  2  1  2  1  3  1  1  1  4  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

You said *"find out the number of persons someone has communicated with"*, suggesting you need to break it down by-person.

Similar data to @bbiasi, though I'll reduce it for readability (since the matrix is large/square):

```r
set.seed(2)
df <- data.frame(V1 = sample(x = 10, size = 50, replace = TRUE),
                 V2 = sample(x = 10, size = 50, replace = TRUE))
(m <- do.call(table, df[1:2]))
#     V2
# V1   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#   1  1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0  0
#   2  1 1 2 2 0 2 1 1 0  1
#   3  0 0 0 2 1 0 0 0 1  0
#   4  1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1  0
#   5  0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1  0
#   6  0 2 0 0 0 0 1 2 0  0
#   7  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1  0
#   8  1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  0
#   9  2 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0  2
#   10 0 0 1 1 3 0 0 0 1  1
```

From this, you can see that (for instance) id 5 (fifth row) communicates with 3 and 7-9. Since I don't infer that your data is perfectly commutative, id 5 (fifth column) is *communicated-to* by id 3 and a lot more by ids 9-10.

If you need it to be commutative (identical across the diagonal), you can force it with:

```r
m[upper.tri(m)] <- m[upper.tri(m)] + m[lower.tri(m)]
m[lower.tri(m)] <- m[upper.tri(m)]
m
#     V2
# V1   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#   1  1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0  0
#   2  1 1 3 2 2 2 1 1 1  1
#   3  0 0 0 2 1 2 0 1 1  0
#   4  3 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1  1
#   5  1 2 1 0 0 1 1 1 1  0
#   6  2 2 1 1 1 0 2 2 3  0
#   7  2 0 2 2 1 0 0 1 4  0
#   8  1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0  0
#   9  2 0 1 0 3 1 0 0 0  3
#   10 1 1 1 1 4 0 0 0 3  1
```

(If the number of columns is fixed, `do.call(...)` can be replaced with `xtabs(~V1+V2, data=df)` or `table(V1=df$V1, V2=df$V2)`.)